# what is the difference between NVL2,NULLIF and COALESCE

Tags: sql

Also how do NVL, NVL2, NULLIF and COALESCE fit in?

Answer (score 4):

NVL : Converts null value to an actual value.

NVL2 : If first expression is not null, return second expression. If first expression is 
null, return third expression. the first expression can have any data type.

COALESCE : Return first not null expression in the expression list.

NULLIF : Compares two expressions and returns null if they are equal,returns the first expression if they are not equal.

Comment: Did you by chance take this answer fully from this blog? If so it would be nice to quote. https://www.fatihacar.com/blog/nvl-nvl2-coalesce-and-nullif-function-in-oracle/